# NGINX mirror files uploaded with HTTP PUT

Tags: nginx

Need to mirror all newly uploaded files from oroginal server to new one.

Direct file upload (HTTP PUT) to new server works fine. When i upload file to original server, file appers only there. Logs on a new server access log:

```
10.31.181.61 - - [28/Dec/2018:13:08:30 +0300] "PUT / HTTP/1.0" 409 167 "-" "curl/7.47.0" "-"
```

error log:

```
2018/12/28 13:08:30 [error] 28983#0: *23 cannot PUT to a collection, client: 10.31.181.61, server: _, request: "PUT / HTTP/1.0", host: "10.31.181.60"
```

what does this error mean: cannot PUT to a collection

Is it possible to make this setup?

Thanks

Nginx config on original server

```
location / {
        autoindex on;
        mirror /mirror;
        mirror_request_body on;
        }

location /mirror {
        proxy_pass http://newserver/; 
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
        }
```

Config on new server:

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /web;
        dav_methods  PUT;

        location / {
        autoindex on;

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should also add the filename to the url that you are using with PUT